# jQuery not running. Isotope sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get jQuery to run on a click but it doesn't give any results.

```
$('.filterbutton').click(function(){
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-option-value');
    console.log(selector);
    $('#isotope-container').isotope({ filter: selector }, function(){
        console.log(selector);
        if(selector == "*"){
            $(".fancybox").attr("data-fancybox-group", "test");
            console.log('test');
        } else{ 
            $(selector).find(".fancybox").attr("data-fancybox-group", selector);
            console.log('finding');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I am getting the selector from the click function, but none of the ones following it.

Comment: show an example for `selector` value.

Comment: and just to be sure, you're wrapping this in  `$(document).ready(function(){ // yourcode });` ?

Comment: `.fc-midtjylland` that is one of the data-option-value

Comment: Yes I am running it inside a `$(document).ready(function(){  });`

Comment: Can you get anything to happen on the click?  Like console logging some string? Have you tried implementing this with `document.on('click', function(){ // yourcode });` instead?

Comment: Yes, when I click it logs the selector, but then it doesn't run the rest of the script.

Comment: Changing to `.on('click')` didn't help either